# Transform the UIView instance

Tags: ios, uiview, transform

I have one view. On single tap, it will show text (it is `UIView` instance).Now i want to transform it.transforming it.But touch point should be same in both case (after transform and before transform).Here touch point is changed after transformation.What should i do?Please help me.Thanking you.Hint will also be appreciated.code :

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"tap stopped" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
angle = (layer.startAngle + layer.endAngle)/2;
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation([self rotationThetaForNewTheta:90 andOldTheta:angle]);

[UIView commitAnimations];
title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Layer %d",i+1];
UIFont* font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
self.popup = [[SNPopupView alloc] initWithString:title withFontOfSize:font.pointSize];
[popup addTarget:self action:@selector(didTouchPopupView:)];
[popup setDelegate:self];
[popup showAtPoint:touchPoint inView:self animated:YES];
```

Here i am adding popup view.after transforming ,it is changing original point.

Comment: Can you show some code, what you have tried ?

Comment: How are you retrieving the touch point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I guess is because `UIView` is changing before you are using the `touchPoint`.
You can use a temp variable to save the `touchPoint` before transformation and use it to appear popup.

**EDIT::**
Either use `UITapGestureRecognizer` object on `ViewController`'s view, keeping the user interaction disabled for your custom View

But if you need user interaction enabled on Custom View, then first find out the location of touch point relating to ViewController's view and appear the popup as well on the ViewController's view.

Use `UIGestureRecognizer` method:
`- (CGPoint)locationInView:(UIView *)view` to find the touch point. Pass ViewController's view in view parameter to get the touchPoint relative to ViewController's view.

Also, use `inView` while making popup appear at the touchPoint. Pass ViewController's view here as well.

Comment: i tried as you said-put popup code before transforming UIView.But still facing same issue.

Comment: How are you getting the touch point? Are you using UITapGestureRecognizer?

Comment: Are you using this view in some other view or ViewController's view as a subview?

Comment: my project structure : User's view controller --> custom UIView --> popup view...

Comment: Disable the user interaction on to your custom view and add tap gesture recognizer on to the underneath view ie. ViewController's View. Your method will then work with slight modifications. Although if you need user interaction on the custom view then we need to look for other options.